# What is the difference between piping an Invoke-WebRequest string into IEX vs the whole IEX New Object Net.Client

Tags: windows, powershell

I've seen this line of powershell to run commands based off of an online string. It goes something like `iex (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("rentry.co/odqgi/raw")`. I've used it for years but I've recently found a simpler solution; a web-request piped to iex like this `Invoke-WebRequest "rentry.co/odqgi/raw" | iex` which seemingly works just the same. Am I missing something or do they really work the same way?

(those urls are not rickrolls that run in powershell)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think ```Invoke-WebRequest``` was introduced until PowerShell 3.0, so it depends on what version you're targeting. Other than that, yeah they're basically the same thing for your purposes...

Comment: @mclayton Yep, it was introduced in 3.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest